# Using Watir and uninitialized constant Watir::RSpec::Core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, watir

I am trying to create a custom rspec formatter using Watir and got this error while executing the class. I have never used Watir before. Do I need some special gems for it?

```
Error: uninitialized constant Watir::RSpec::Core (NameError)
```

My code:

```
require 'rspec/core/formatters/html_formatter'
module Watir
  class RSpec
    class CustomFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean you are trying to create a rspec formatter using Watir? Watir is for driving browsers, so I am not sure why it would be used to create the rspec report formatter.

Comment: I am not driving through the browsers, I am testing an app and trying to report its results on a browser using the rspec formatter. This formatter doesn't display screen shots using rspec and I read that Watir does, so was trying it out. As I am noob to ruby and rspec, I would appreciate if you share some other thoughts for test reporting with screen shots. :)

Comment: I am still not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but you might want to look at the [watir-rspec gem](https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

The exception is occurring because of the class that the `CustomFormatter` is trying to inherit from. Due to the location, it is look for the `RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter` class within the scope of the `Watir::RSpec` class.

Usually custom formatters are done as:

```
require 'rspec/core/formatters/html_formatter'

class CustomFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter
end
```

You do not need to put it in a `Watir::RSpec` space.

Comment: I tried it but something strange is going around. If I remove the Watir::Rspec and run the formatter command, my test folder where all the tests are lying gets deleted on its own. Very strange, but if you faced any similar thing before please suggest. Am looking into it now.